# HTML5-compliant cache-control no-cache inside the document?

Tags: html, no-cache

This is probably a duplicate question but none of the solutions I've found by searching the internet will validate at w3c.

I don't have granular control at the document-level on the hosting-company's server, so I need to include the no-cache directive in the document itself.  Are cache directives inside the document permitted in HTML5?  If so, how is it done so it validates?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer in your answer also to <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />

Answer (score 0):

I could find no evidence that html5 still supports this functionality. More info is here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: Even though W3Schools can be a great place to learn the basics, I don't think it's considered an authorative reference (at least not on SO), perhaps you can add links to W3 or MDN to your answer?